# Inverting matrix multiplication "and" representing with a smaller sized matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Consider I have a vector $A=[a_0 \ \ a_1]$ and a random binary matrix $B$ which is  $2\times 2$. I compute $C=A\cdot B$.

My question is: " Can one compute $B$ Given $C$ and $A$? "

Note: By binary matrix I mean the entries of matrix $B$ can be $0$ or $1$. Also not all entries of $A$ and $B$ are zero. $A$ can be a binary vector too.

Comment: If $A$ and $C$ are both zero matrices, then you cannot recover $B$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 I've added more stuff to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Do you intend for multiplication to be done modulo 2? That is, for instance, are the matrices $[ 2 0 ]$ and $[ 0 0 ]$ for $C$ the same?

Comment: @rogerl I think this is a general linear algebra question, I don't think it matters in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix} b_1 & b_2 \\ b_3 & b_4 \end{bmatrix}
$$
where the $b_i$ are all $0$ or $1$.  Then
$$
C=AB=\begin{bmatrix} a_1b_1+a_2b_3 & a_1b_2+a_2b_4 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Suppose that $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.  Then $C=\begin{bmatrix} b_1 & b_2 \end{bmatrix}$.  So, you would not be able to recover $b_3$ and $b_4$.

Comment: Definitely not all entries of $B$ are zero. Also I can make  $B$ to have mixture of $0$ and $1$ too.

Answer (score 1):

There's no straightforward way to compute B from C and A since C and A are nonsquare and therefore noninvertible.

Comment: $A$ and $C$ are both $1\times 2$ vectors...

Comment: Let me slightly change the question. If we keep matrix $B$ the same as before, but make matrix $A$ $2\times 2$ matrix, that have an specific property (say a magic property). Then $C= A\cdot B$. My question is " Can we make a $C$ as a vector? " For instance $C$ which would be $2\times 2$ always has some zero rows or columns at an specific position so we can ignore it.        Reason why I need this property: If I can make  $C$ to be represented in a smaller size than $B$, I would be able to save some communication cost. so instead of sending $B$ I send $C$.